# Spring Transactional does not roll back

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have a question about xml-free configuration of Spring. Unfortunately it does not roll back my DB changes even if I mark a corresponding method with `@Transactional` annotation.

First of all I have a controller, which calls a class marked with `@Transactional`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Device", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody List<Device> addDevice(
        @RequestBody Device deviceToAdd) {      

    List<Device> devices= deviceManager.addDevice(deviceToAdd);
    return devices;
}
```

All controllers have an ExceptionResolver that catches `DuplicateKeyException`:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DuplicateKeyException.class)      
public ResponseEntity<Result> handleBindException(DuplicateKeyException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    Result result = new Result("this object already exists");       
    return new Response(result);
}
```

Here is my main transactional class which calls two DAO classes. The second one causes `DuplicateKeyException`, but the results of the first one are not deleted from DB.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class DeviceManager {

@Autowired
DaoClass1 daoClass1;

@Autowired
DaoClass2 daoClass2;    

public List<Device> addDevice(Device device){       

    Pocket pocket = daoClass1.addPocket(new Pocket());<--is not rolled back after Exception
    device.setPocket(pocket);

    List<Devices> addedDevices = daoClass2.addDevice(device); <--- causes exception
    return devices;
}
```

I tried also to use `@Transactional` annotation both for the classes `daoClass1` and `daoClass2`, but it did not change anything.

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: show your data source configuration

Comment: Your implementation seems ok. it may comes from the PlatformTransactionManager. Do you know which implementation of the transaction-manager you are using?

Comment: please share your configuration code.

Comment: Let me guess... You have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`. Both with a `<context:component-scan />` or `@ComponentScan` scanning for the same components. Only the `ContextLoaderListener` contains `<tx:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableTransactionManagement`?

Comment: @AlecKravets @shankarsh, my data source configuration file seems like:

`@Bean
public DaoClass1 daoClass1(){ return new DaoClass1()}`

Comment: @M.Deinum, it is DataSourceTransactionManager

Comment: Only having a transaction manager without either `<tx:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableTransactionManagement` doesn't do anything. Also read the comment.